# Problema com variável de conexão ao Banco C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, conexão, visual-studio-2017

Tenho minha string de conexão que pega a variável de conexão do App.Config

```
static String string_conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bd1"].ConnectionString;
```

Porém eu coloquei uma função que lista os bancos em um Combobox no form login e manda o nome da conexão para esse form principal que contem a conexão acima, porem eu preciso que esse valor que vem do form login fique no lugar desse

> ConnectionStrings**["bd1"]**

por exmplo:

```
   String nomeConexao = Form1.LoginInfo.StringConexao;

static String string_conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[nomeConexao ].ConnectionString;
```

Ou seja no lugar de

```
ConnectionStrings["bd1"]
```

Fique

```
ConnectionStrings[nomeConexao ]
```

só que da erro, ele não aceita a variável mesmo sendo uma string o que eu posso fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver!
Eu estava colocando o trecho de código no lugar errado, foi descuido meu.

Eu estava colocando fora da função de click do botão.

Answer (score 1):

Minha sugestão seria fazer o seguinte.

Declarar a sua variável de conexão assim:

```
string _conn;
```

E no evento de mudança do `index` do seu `ComboBox`, colocar o seguinte código:

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedConn = (sender as ComboBox).Text;

    _conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[selectedConn].ConnectionString;
}
```

Dessa forma, após selecionar a conexão desejada no `ComboBox`, você teria a conexão desejada na variável global `_conn`.